# Interrupt Service Routine can't be called directly

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, kernel, interrupt-handling

I am trying to code an Interrupt Handler in C++ without the use of Assembly through `__attribute__((interrupt))`.

Following code:
init/idt.cpp:

```
void set(IDTDescr *descriptor, void(*handler)(void), uint8_t flags)
{
    descriptor->selector = 0x08;

    uintptr_t handler_addr = (uintptr_t)handler;
    descriptor->offset_1 = handler_addr & 0xFFFF;
    descriptor->offset_2 = (handler_addr >> 16) & 0xFFFF;
    descriptor->offset_3 = (handler_addr >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF;

    descriptor->flags = flags;
}
void init(void)
{
    memset(descriptors, 0, sizeof(descriptors));

    //Faults:
    set(&descriptors[0x00], &DivideByZero,              IDT_PRESENT | IDT_INTERRUPT);
    set(&descriptors[0x01], &Debug,                     IDT_PRESENT | IDT_INTERRUPT);
```

and so on.

interrupt/handler/stubs.h:

```
//Faults:
void DivideByZero(struct cpu_state *state);
void Debug(struct cpu_state *state);
```

and so on.

interrupt/handler/fault_irs.cpp:

```
__attribute__((interrupt)) void DivideByZero(struct cpu_state *state)
{
    Text::Clear();
    Text::Simple::Write("FAULT!");
    abort();
}

__attribute__((interrupt)) void Debug(struct cpu_state *state)
{
    Text::Clear();
    Text::Simple::Write("FAULT!");
    abort();
}
```

and so on.

The problem is that GCC tells me that i can't call a ISR directly. But i don't call it directly, do I? Do I have to define `__attribute__((interrupt))` in `void set` too?

Would it maybe help if i would set the arguments in stubs.h to void?

The funny thing is that the first fault is accepted by gcc...

It seams like gcc wants me to put all isr's in a seperate file... If i do the same in interrupt/handler/irq_irs.cpp it works....

Maybe an additional explanation why i don't want to simply use a single Interrupt Handler: If i use a single IH, i'll have to use a switch-case to call the right function for handling the interrupt (because i can't put all of the handling code in the handler i'll have to use seperate functions). That's much overhead and doesn't really make things simpler... Even if i really have to create a file for 256 interrupts...

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem was that gcc 7.0 didn't allow me to put more then one isr into a single file. I had to put each isr into a seperate file, then it worked. But it seems to be fixed in gcc 7.1. At least i can't recreate the problem, neither in my kernel nor in a seperate test file.